# How to Convert string of HTML tags to Array ? I'm Trying but "data-href{=+data[i].url+}" not working

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs, for-loop

[image]

below is the code,please help on this

```
( < div dangerouslySetInnerHTML = {

        {
            __html: '<div class=col-md-6 col-lg-4 text-center> <div class=card mb-4 ><div class=fb-page data-href{=+data[i].url+} data-tabs=cover data-width= data-height= data-small-header=true data-adapt-container-width=true data-hide-cover=false data-show-facepile=false><div class=card-body>  <button id{=+data[i].id+} value{=+data[i].status+} disabled=disable style={{ width: 100px }} ref=fbl class=btn btn-primary mt-2 >{+data[i].status+}</button> <p id=Liked></p>    </div></div></div>'
        }
    }
    />)});
```

Comment: please format your code to help readers understand your code (e.g.: use code blocks, indent with spaces)

Answer (score 0):

“data-href{=+data[i].url+}”  Remove double quote in full code

correct answer

**data-href="+data[i].url+"**